# How to get the values of several xml tags and pass them to the url as a string using Freemarker

Tags: spring-boot, freemarker

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <tns:Map xmlns:tns="urn://xxx" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <tns:type>2</tns:type>
            <tns:code>CAT</tns:code>
            <tns:code>DOG</tns:code>
        </tns:Map>
```

**it needs to be like this** - http://test.com/test/CAT,DOG

i tried like this(and other options):

```
<#ftl ns_prefixes={"ns1":"urn://xxx", "ns2":"urn://xxx"}>
    <#assign type = body["ns1:Request"]["ns1:Content"]["ns2:Map"]["ns2:type"]>
    <#if type?number == 1> 
     http://test.com/somePath
    <#elseif type?number == 2>
     <#list body["ns1:Request"]["ns1:Content"]["ns2:Map"] as codeList>
     <#assign codes = codeList["ns2:code"]> 
     http://test.com/test/${codes} 
     </#list>
    </#if>
```

but it throws an syntax error.

And with this code I can get only the first element, but how to display all? using http://test.com/test/${codes?join(", ")} doesn't help:

```
<#ftl ns_prefixes={"ns1":"urn://xxx", "ns2":"urn://xxx"}>
    <#assign type = body["ns1:Request"]["ns1:Content"]["ns2:Map"]["ns2:type"]>
    <#assign codes = body["ns1:Request"]["ns1:Content"]["ns2:Map"]["ns2:code"]?sequence>
    <#if type?number == 1> 
     http://test.com/somePath
    <#elseif type?number == 2> 
     http://test.com/test/${codes[0]}
    </#if>
```

how to write list tns:code to variable?

Comment: Why does this start with `body["ns1:Request"]["ns1:Content"]` when the document element is `tns:Map`? Also "throws an error" is not very helpful.

Comment: Edited the question. xml wrapped with tags["ns1:Request"]["ns1:Content"]. Syntax error, with a different approach, different errors fall. I just need to figure out how to get a list of values in the needed tags and display them.

Comment: Always paste the actual (and full) error message, and a *minimal*, but working example. If you don't put your time into making you questions succinct, and complete, people just skip your question. Anyway, the solution with `?join` looks fine to me, so what exactly the error is, and with what exact template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### solution:

```
<#ftl ns_prefixes={"ns1":"urn://xxx", "ns2":"urn://xxx"}>
    <#assign type = body["ns1:Request"]["ns1:Content"]["ns2:Map"]["ns2:type"]>
    <#if type?number == 1> 
     http://test.com/somePath
    <#elseif type?number == 2>
     <#assign codes = body["ns1:Request"]["ns1:Content"]["ns2:Map"]["ns2:code"]>
     http://test.com/test/${codes?join(",")}
    </#if>
```